# Quick edit db rows using bootstrap model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I have created a view that shows all images used in Carousel. This is my method in controller
My edit method:

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $carousel = Carousel::find($id)->first();
    return view('admin.partials._edit-modal.blade');
}
```

My route for edit:

```
Route::get('carousel.edit/{id}',['as' => 'carousel.edit', 'uses' => 'LinkController@edit']);
```

This is my code to display it in view:

```
@foreach($carousels as $carousel)
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 grid">
    <a href="{{ url($carousel->path) }}" class="thumbnail" data-lity>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $carousel->path }}" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

I've set up a button to open a model that shows the selected image and form to edit the image name [ Form not setup yet, shows only image].
My model code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $carousel->path }}" alt="">
     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

There is no error in code but when the edit button is clicked it is always showing the last image of the table. Whether I click edit button of first,second or any image. The model always shows the last image.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the view / controller code for the all images where `$carousels` gets populated / presented.

Comment: view populating controller `public function index()
    {
        $carousels = Carousel::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(12);
        return view('admin.carousels.index')->withCarousels($carousels);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

When showing the images with a foreach() loop you should include the button to edit that image including the id of the image and pass this id to the modal. Something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="edit-image" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myEditImageModal" data_value="{{ $image->id }}"> Edit</button>
```

Then add a script to pass that specific id when the button is clicked to the modal. You can accomplish this with js:

```
<script>
// pass image id to modal
$('.edit-image').click(function() {
  $("#image_id").val($(this).attr('data_value'));
});
</script>
```

Finally the modal will receive that id and you can store it in a hidden input field inside your form. Something like this:

```
<div id="myEditImageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade">
...
<form>
...
<input type="hidden" name="image_id" id="image_id">
...
</form>
...
</div>
```

- Place the modal outside the foreach loop.

Comment: I didn't get you. Where should i put `"#image_id"` in loop ?

Comment: #image_id is present in the script and inside the modal. The script takes the data_value from the button (the button is placed inside the foreach loop available for every image). Then the script stores this data_value in the element that has the id of #image_id, which is the hidden input field inside the modal form.